# Firebase Messaging > https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/dr-plano/registrations responds with invalid argument

Tags: javascript, firebase, firefox, firebase-cloud-messaging

we use Firebase to implement web push-notification. I tested our implementation on multiple devices and it works fine. Only on a single device (Firefox, Windows 11) we are getting an error, and I am clueless. Hopefully, somebody has an idea.

We use Firebase JavaScript SDK. The service-worker is pretty standard:

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...',
  appId: '...',
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

We register the service-worker manually and then get the token with the following code:

```
getToken(this.messaging, {
    vapidKey: this.VAPID_KEY,
    serviceWorkerRegistration: this.serviceWorker
}).then((token) => {
    // store the token
})
```

As I said, this setup works fine for multiple tested devices. On the Firefox (Windows 11) device with problems the call to `POST https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/dr-plano/registrations` gives the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The payload to the API call is:

```
{
  "web": {
    "endpoint": "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v2/gAAAAABju_PDv-sqOv-BT13zqOdPb53vQzspTgrTex_vBnKUFfkLsU_sdikXdcMiTbjGazHO5Hr3U_OpvLMXZoX9FP1o5gz3PSInxS6KAORmDfUxzuVtaW5Mnyy8wHOvkF5MpmsfH_KKFgPOol8Z3A-IlRoCLXoYuWIeuvSMRtz-N3ZnfnQmoZ8",
    "auth": "...",
    "p256dh": "...",
    "applicationPubKey": "..."
  }
}
```

I have anonymized project specific data with `...`. Let me know if anything is relevant.

I have tried removing the service-worker and letting it be recreated. And also resetting the permission for getting notifications in the Firefox browser. Nothing helped. I would appreciate any idea.

Regards,
Milad